# How to get wave audio data from m4a file

Tags: winapi, audio, ms-media-foundation

How do I get raw audio data from .m4a file using MS Media Foundation API ?
IMFSample gives me some buffers, but it doesn't look like raw wave (maybe it's encoded/compressed some way)

Comment: I suggest you could try to use the [Source Reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/source-reader). For more details, you could refer to the Doc: [Using the Source Reader to Process Media Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/processing-media-data-with-the-source-reader)

Answer (score 0):

Basically what I needed was to set a current media type (MFMediaType_Audio, MFAudioFormat_PCM) for the source reader